# How to remove content-disposition from upload file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried other solution get from SO to remove and upload the file without `content-header`

but still it wont work

My code is below

```
def upload_file(fpath):
     headers = {
         'Api-Key': sys.argv[16]
     }
     files = {'file': open(fpath, 'r').read()}
     response = requests.request("PUT", +"https://abcd.om/inventory/"+str(sys.argv[3]), headers=headers, files=files)
```

But still it get

```
--9bcf1c0247af690b91cad8f301346f2e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file"
```

in end

-9bcf1c0247af690b91cad8f301346f2e--

Any help would

Comment: I am not sure if this helps but one of the underlying packages 
`requests`  --> imports --> `urllib3`  --> imports --> `http` is injecting the required header.
The RFC7578 tells that this header is mandatory for multipart data.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578#section-4.2 so I am not sure if this will be possible to remove it, because it would cause sending unvalid http request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it by below

```
 response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=open(fpath,'rb').read())
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the request in wrote in the question is a `multipart/form-data` because you used the `files` argument, this is the norm for files uploading.
In this response you use `data`, which uses `x-www-form-urlencoded`.
`Content-Disposition` is mandatory for `multipart/form-data`.